# Using existing ActiveMQ "Classic" JCA RA in JBoss EAP 7.4 to connect to ActiveMQ Artemis remote servers by changes to configuration

Tags: java, jboss, jms, activemq-artemis

Is it possible to repurpose existing code connecting to ActiveMQ "Classic" to connect to ActiveMQ Artemis by changes to configuration? If so what are the important parameters that need to be modified?

Current software is deployed on JBoss EAP 7.4.2 and communicates with 2 remote ActiveMQ "Classic" servers that provide support for failover/ha.

In the new architecture the ActiveMQ "Classic" servers will get replaced by 3 independent ActiveMQ Artemis servers (version 2.16.0) which will provide failover/HA. Support for embedded ActiveMQ Artemis in JBoss EAP will not be utilized.

ActiveMQ resource adapter settings:

```xml
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:resource-adapters:6.0">
        <resource-adapters>
            <resource-adapter id="org.apache.activemq">
                <module slot="main" id="org.apache.activemq"/>
                <config-property name="RedeliveryBackOffMultiplier">3</config-property>
                <config-property name="ServerUrl">failover:(tcp://x.y.z.49:61616,tcp://x.y.z.50:61616)?randomize=false&amp;jms.watchTopicAdvisories=false&amp;timeout=3000</config-property>
                <config-property name="RedeliveryUseExponentialBackOff">false</config-property>
                <config-property name="UserName">user</config-property>
                <config-property name="MaximumRedeliveries">1</config-property>
                <config-property name="UseInboundSession">true</config-property>
                <config-property name="Password">password</config-property>
                <connection-definitions>
                    <connection-definition class-name="org.apache.activemq.ra.ActiveMQManagedConnectionFactory" jndi-name="java:/ConnectionFactory" enabled="true" tracking="false" use-java-context="true" pool-name="ConnectionFactory">
                        <config-property name="UseInboundSession">false</config-property>
                        <pool>
                            <min-pool-size>4</min-pool-size>
                            <max-pool-size>256</max-pool-size>
                            <prefill>true</prefill>
                        </pool>
                        <timeout>
                            <blocking-timeout-millis>12000</blocking-timeout-millis>
                            <idle-timeout-minutes>5</idle-timeout-minutes>
                        </timeout>
                    </connection-definition>
                </connection-definitions>
```

JNDI is used to lookup the connection factory, using `InitialContext` as shown in the following code

```java
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;

import javax.ejb.Singleton;
import javax.ejb.Startup;

@Singleton
@Startup
public class BootClass {
    ....
    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        try {
            // "java/ConnectionFactory" defined in resource adapter
            final ConnectionFactory cf = (ConnectionFactory) (new InitialContext()).lookup("java:/ConnectionFactory");
            
            // cf is used with Camel JMS component
```

Comment: Generally speaking, yes. You can repurpose existing code using the JMS API between any compliant broker. The ability to change implementations without changing code is one of the main benefits of using an API in the first place. However, your title mentions JBoss EAP and ActiveMQ pooled connection factory, but your question says nothing about them. Please elaborate as to how these things are involved in your use-case as that may change the answer to your question.

Comment: I edited the question and added information about the resource adapter settings. Pls let me know if you need any additional information. Thx

Comment: Are you going to use the instance of ActiveMQ Artemis embedded in JBoss EAP or are you going to use a standalone instance? Also, how are you using the connection factory? Are you injecting it? Are you looking it up in JNDI via `InitialContext`? Can you provide the code that's using it?

Comment: ActiveMQ Artemis embedded in JBoss EAP is not utilized. There will be 3 independent Artemis servers (provide support for failover/HA). The connection factory is defined in resource adapter, and is looked up via InitialContext. Sample code using JNDI lookup has been added to the question

Answer (score 0):

Technically speaking you don't actually need to change anything in JBoss EAP because ActiveMQ Artemis supports the OpenWire protocol which is used by ActiveMQ "Classic".

Comment: Thanks Justin. I will check this out and provide the results as soon as possible

Comment: Any feedback so far?

Comment: Hi Justin. Unfortunately, it may take a few days to test this, but will try this out ASAP